# Is nfs4_setfacl supposed to be applied from the client machine or server?

Tags: linux, centos, nfsv4

I'm really confused on NFSv4, specifically, I don't understand how to set the permissions. When I attempt to use the command `nfs4_setfacl` I get error message `Operation to request attribute not supported: /data` and `Failed to instantiate ACL.` I have all the packages for NFSv4 installed. Some of the posts I have read seem to suggest clients can apply NFS permissions via `nfs4_setacl` ?

I know my issue is a lack of understanding, so I'd like to find a tutorial or a manual that is a bit easier to understand than the official documentation. An overview explanation on NFSv4 would be greatly appreciated.